# Set a Typescript array as undefined

Tags: typescript

I'm developing an Angular 2 application. This the first time I do something with Angular or Typescript.

I have this variable inside of a class:

```
public products: IProduct[];
```

`IProduct` is:

```
interface IProduct {
    productCode: string;
    description: string;
    lawId: number;
    name: string;
    comment: string;
    emvoProduct?: IEmvoProduct; // ?: Optional.
}
```

Is there any way to set it to undefined?

When I do this:

```
this.products = undefined;
```

I get an error saying:

> (TS) Type 'undefined' cannot be converted to type 'IProduct[]'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its because of `strictNullChecks` compile option in your `tsconfig.json`; you can simply remove or set to false.

Alternatively, you have to specify that the field can be undefined:

```
products: IProduct[] | undefined
```

Another alternative is to `delete`

```
delete this.products
```

this will truly make the field `undefined` when you check for it because its simply not there. typescript will be happy with it -- even with `strictNullCheck: true`

Comment: The `delete` idea isn't _exactly_ the same, as it will remove the key `products` entirely, rather than setting it to undefined. So `this.products` will evaluate to `undefined`, but for a different reason.

Comment: Probably I haven't express myself correctly but `delete this.products` is what I need because if I use `products: IProduct[] | undefined` I can't use `this.products.splice(rowNumber, 1);`.

Comment: @TomFenech you're totally correct; `products` key will _not_ be on `Object.keys(container)` if you delete it. that said; an argument could be make that if you want the key, but no value you should be setting it to `null`.

Comment: @VansFannel you _can_ use array methods, you just need to check whether it's an array first. I updated my answer.

Comment: Better to set `strictNullChecks` to false as you say, instead of using hacky `undefined` as type. I prefer using `null` instead of `undefined`, but I guess that is only opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` is its own type, so you would need to change your declaration to:

```
public products: IProduct[]?; // optional property
// or
public products: IProduct[] | undefined; // explicit intersection with undefined
```

Now that `products` isn't necessarily an array, you need to use a type guard before treating it as an array. We don't need to write our own, as we can use `instanceof Array`, which is recognised by TypeScript as a type guard:

```
if (this.products instanceof Array) {
    // use this.products as an array
}
```

Alternatively, you can set `strictNullChecks` to `false` (either by removing the compiler switch `--strictNullChecks`, or in your `tsconfig.json`), so that `null` or `undefined` are permitted values of every type. Personally I would recommend against doing this, and trying to handle possible `null`s and `undefined`s on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't assign any value to it and it will remain undefined.

public products: IProduct[];

Comment: Thanks but I want to set it undefined when it has a value assigned.